# Is it possible to create Lightroom / Flickr captions in two languages?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, flickr

I need to export images from Lightroom 5 to Flickr/Web with the captions in two different languages; English and Russian.

Are there any methods/tools to facilitate this process without mixing two languages within one caption?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Lightroom will not allow multiple language EXIF entry but even if you found a work around, the Flickr API will not support it.

I think your idea of entering both languages into the caption is the only option.

Answer (score 3):

You can write bilingual captions in the exif data, but the text in both languages should be written in the same caption field.

If you want to have two exif fields with one caption each you could use another exif field for that purpose since you can not just add a "caption2" field to the exif data out of nowhere.

Same thing for flickr: You can add text in any language you want to the photo description, but all the text will be on the same photo description no matter what language you are writing in.

I tried to do something like this last year and writing everything into a single caption field and description was the less painful way to go. If you REALLY want to go for it no matter what, the best solution I can think of is to misuse one exif field for the alternate caption and then create or find a script that joins those two captions and dumps them into the flickr photo description.

Comment: The [exif specification](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) allows for `Comment` and `UserComment` fields but any software that reads it will probably only use one of those fields, not both.

Comment: @JamesSnell Good point. I was thinking about Lightroom and other known software thought (None I know have that feature). Maybe there is an option out there that makes use of both fields, if it is similar to LR OP may want to try it out, and I would definitely be interested too.